# How do I create a nuget package to reference a COM Imterop dll?

Tags: nuget

I am having trouble getting a nuget package to correctly add a COM interop DLL to my project. The nuget documentation (especially the section on COM interops) is a little unclear, so I hope someone can fill in the gaps.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.

Here is my nuspec file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>MyInteropLibs</id>
        <version>1.0.1</version>
    <title>Does stuff</title>
        <authors>me</authors>
    <description>My COM Interop DLL</description>
    <summary>ditto</summary>
    <copyright>me</copyright>
  </metadata>
  <files>
    <file src="..\AxVCF150.DLL" target="lib" />
    <file src="..\VCF150.DLL" target="build" /> <!--the interop-->
    <file src="VCF150Interop.targets"/>
  </files>
</package>
```

and here is my accompanying Targets file (VCF150Interop.targets) :

```
  <Target Name="Unique.VCF150" AfterTargets="ResolveReferences" BeforeTargets="FindReferenceAssembliesForReferences">
  <PropertyGroup>
  <InteropAssemblyName>VCF150</InteropAssemblyName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ReferencePath Condition=" '%(FileName)' == '{InteropAssemblyName}' AND '%(ReferencePath.NuGetPackageId)' == '$(MSBuildThisFileName)' ">
      <EmbedInteropTypes>false</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </ReferencePath>
  </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

As far as I can tell this is exactly what the documentation prescribes, and the built package when inspected seems to have the right files in the right places in the package. However when I install it in the project using the nuget package manager, only AxVCF150.dll is added as a reference and the interop dll is completely ignored.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

It may sound absurd. Have you tried changing the name of the dll target?
for example: VCF150.DLL to interop.VCF150.DLL

```
  <files>
    <file src="..\AxVCF150.DLL" target="lib" />
    <file src="..\VCF150.DLL" target="interop.VCF150.DLL" /> <!--the interop-->
  </files>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm retired now so no longer relevant to me, but thanks for taking the trouble to answer.